# Minidom - iterate through attributes and get their value

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I have the following code which tries to fetch the value of feature attribute tag in XML;

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('P38398.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("feature")
for s in itemlist:
    description = s.attributes['description'].value
    print description
```

This loop gives me the following error. Why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
description = s.attributes['description'].value
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 522, in __getitem__
return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]
KeyError: 'description'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Below is the XML file.

```
<root>
    <entry>
      <accession>A</accession>
        <feature type="cross-link" description="sumo2">
            <location>
                <position position="15111992"/>
            </location>
        </feature>
        <feature type="cross-link" description="sumo">
            <location>
                <position position="22345"/>
            </location>
        </feature>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <accession>X</accession>
        <feature type="test" description="testing">
            <location>
                <position position="1"/>
            </location>
        </feature>
        <feature type="cross-link" description="sumo hello">
            <location>
                <position position="11223344"/>
            </location>
        </feature>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Comment: Where does the `entry` variable come from in your code?  It would make more sense to me if you wrote `xmldoc.getElementyByTagName`

Comment: `KeyError: 'description'` means that the `s.attributes` dict does not have an entry with the key `'description'`. Did you check if all of your feature elements have a description attribute in your XML? If it does, could you please upload the relevant parts of that XML file?

Comment: @AlbertP XML Added.

Comment: I ran your code with the given XML, but it worked for me. The four description attributes were printed correctly, without any error. I was using Python 2.7.12, but I don't think that the problem is with your version.

Comment: Looks like this is an old thread, but I also ran this (v2.7.15) and it worked.